# I am trying to detect rectangle shape paper with blue colour using opencv.js (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, opencv, shapes

I'm trying to detect the rectangle shape and blue color target but when I try to run this code I'm getting some error. Did I miss any code please guide me, I'm using **`opencv.js`** `(javascript).`

I tried This.

```
function findMarker(video){
    let gray = cv.cvtColor(video, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
    let blur = cv.blur(gray, ksize, anchor, cv.BORDER_DEFAULT); // blur the image to avoids noise 
    let edges = cv.Canny(blur, 50, 100, 3, false); // black and white border 
    let cnts = cv.findContours(edges.copy(), cv.RETR_CCOMP, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE); 
    c = max(cnts, key = cv.contourArea);
    return cv.minAreaRect(c);
}
```

**Error Code**

```
BindingError {name: "BindingError", message: "Function 'cvtColor' called with an invalid number … arg0Wired, arg1Wired, arg2Wired, arg3Wired);↵})!", stack: "BindingError: Function 'cvtColor' called with an i…20OpenCV%20js/utils.js:68:13), <anonymous>:24:23)"}
```

Comment: What are the errors you're getting?

Comment: BindingError {name: "BindingError", message: "Function 'cvtColor' called with an invalid number … arg0Wired, arg1Wired, arg2Wired, arg3Wired);↵})!", stack: "BindingError: Function 'cvtColor' called with an i…20OpenCV%20js/utils.js:68:13), <anonymous>:24:23)"}

Comment: I'm not too familiar with OpenCV but what I've seen from the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) `cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY` should be the third parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your question contains too little useful info and the title is misleading.

You had a bug in running a function. Try to add more description, like where you call this, whats the video contains and whats the complete error.

But based on my experience, you could start off the debug first by

first, for each stage, display image to debug eg video gray blur edge image.  just to know where the problem is.

Second, the input to convert function should be current frame aka Mat. Did you just pass the video class to the convert function?

Last but not the least, you can follow other people implementation to try out e.g

https://android.jlelse.eu/a-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-opencv-android-library-on-android-studio-19794e220f3c

try to learn how they use mRBGA in the sample section of the linked tutorial. I tested this just now, it is working. So I think you can learn from them on the proper routing

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you call cvtColor with the wrong arguments: you need to pass to the function first the source frame, then the destination mat, then the color conversion code

Try like this

```
let src = cv.imread('canvasInput');
let dst = new cv.Mat();
cv.cvtColor(src, dst, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 0);
```

here the [reference](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d64/tutorial_js_colorspaces.html)

edit: I'm also not quite sure also about the function parameter: you named it video, due to this(and if you pass an actual video flow) I think you need to extract frames from the video before converting